# Android - How to pass data to a class that does not have onCreate etc?

Tags: android

I've viewed this site many times and have always found the help I need, however today I find myself needing to ask a question.
I'm trying to learn Java for Android and I am using two pieces of source code that I found online.
I have source for a game, and I also have googles Bluetooth Chat demo source.
I am trying to add bluetooth for multiplayer but have run into a problem.
From one of the game files I am trying to access data from one of the bluetooth files, but every attempt leads to a null pointer exception.
I'm having problems because the game file seems to be just a collection of functions (maybe you call them methods? My background is vb).
From what I have seen so far the ability to pass data between classes would be set up within the onCreate? Maybe I've got that wrong?
The problem is the game file does not have onCreate onStart etc, I'm also suspecting the game file is running on its own thread, could that be the problem?
Just hoping for a few pointers in the right direction :)
Thanks.

Comment: *but every attempt leads to a null pointer exception.* - You need to include your attempt in your question.

Comment: @BSMP 
I've been stuck on this for several days and as soon as I posted on here I found a solution.  

In the Bluetooth file I added this.  
   public final int isBluetoothOn() {  
         return isBluetoothoOn;  
  }  


In the game file I added this.  
        BluetoothChat getbluetooth = new BluetoothChat();  
        iAmMultyplayer = getbluetooth.isBluetoothOn();  



I'm using iAmMultyplayer to skip a piece of code if Bluetooth is off.  

I nolonger get the null pointer exception but now get error about reslooper so more research :)  

Thanks